# Keyboard hides the text input inside WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to create a web view that opens up an external website. The problem is when I click in a text input to enter text, the keyboard opens up, and moves the page up causing the text input to disappear. I have to manually scroll down to the text input. Nothing I try works. What am I doing wrong?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.webView.webView">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WebActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/webview">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="webview" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

activity_web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".WebActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        >

    </include>


    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

app_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressWifi"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBattery"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:iiv_color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:iiv_icon="gmd-print" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

WebActivity.java

```
public class WebActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.webview) WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       //webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101Firefox/4.0");
        webView.loadUrl("https://externalurl.com");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("Page finished " + url);
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 THIS IS XML FILE:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/web">

    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
IN A MAINACITIVITY:
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      WebView webView;//YOU NEED TO DECLARE A WEBVIEW

    enter code here
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView =  findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.loadUrl("http://cloudanalogy.com/");

    }
}
YOU CAN TRY WITH THIS CODE
```